# Creative easy combinatorics problems.

Tags: combinatorics, big-list

I would like cool problems of the following style: how many marbles need to be taken out of a jar to guarantee we have one of each color? I need some cool problems for some classes I want to give to my math olympiad teammates. Thank you very much

Regards.

Comment: I think a good big-list question should specify exactly what kind of problem it is looking for, not just a general statement like "creative easy combinatorics problems."

Comment: I wan't that type of problems, asking how many marbles you need to take out to guarrantee. easy combinatorial maximization problems are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little harder than your example, but ...

A jar contains 50 white marbles and 50 black marbles.  You will play a game where you draw one marble at a time (uniformly at random, without replacement), and you can stop any time you like.  Your score is (whites drawn - blacks drawn).  What strategy should you play to maximize your expected score?

Comment: My first guess would be "don't draw any marbles." :)

Comment: Alternately, "draw all the marbles" also gets you a score of 0.  And that way you get to draw marbles =)

Comment: Draw until you're ahead and then quit.

Comment: Sounds like something related to sultan drowry.

Comment: "Draw until you're ahead" isn't right, if I remember correctly.  If your first draw is white, you should keep going, because there's a pretty good chance you'll hit +2 at some point in the future (even if your next draw drops you back to 0).